# Odd behavior from MPMapView

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

I have a `getLocation` button in my app that gets the user's current location, the button calls the following method:

```
-(void)setOriginalRegion {
    float spanX = 0.217;
    float spanY = 0.217;
    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    region.center.latitude = self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate.latitude;
    region.center.longitude = self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate.longitude;
    region.span.latitudeDelta = spanX;
    region.span.longitudeDelta = spanY;
    [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}
```

That works just fine, and when tapped I get my location and a 15mile radius (as set by the delta's)...

To make sure my map loads up in the current user's location, I have added the following in my `viewWillAppear` method:

```
[self setOriginalRegion];
```

But that is starting the map somewhere in the middle of the ocean (approx 100 miles off the coast of Ghana.... This of course is not default, because by default it loads up in with North America. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: How about call your function AFTER get the userLocation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @AndreMunis, `viewWillAppear` is too soon to know user's location, moved my method call to `viewDidAppear` and code works like a charm!